# How to display sub category images on main category page in Opencart?

Tags: php, image, opencart, categories

I have an Opencart website where I want to display the sub categories with thumbnails when I click on any product categories page.

This is the code I edited inside the *foreach ($results as $result)* loop in catalog/controller/product/category.php

```
    if ($result['image'] && file_exists(DIR_IMAGE.$result['image'])) {
        $thumb = $this->model_tool_image->resize(DIR_IMAGE.$result['image'], 100, 100);
    } else {
        $thumb = $this->model_tool_image->resize(DIR_IMAGE.'placeholder.png', 100, 100);
    }

    $data['categories'][] = array(
        'name' => $result['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
        'thumb' = $thumb,
        'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '_' . $result['category_id'] . $url));
```

Below is the code I edited in the catalog/view/theme/elevt/template/common

```
      <div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 category_list">
            {% for category in categories %}
              <div class="row category_thumb">
                {% if thumb %}
                <div class="col-sm-2 category_img"><img src="{{ category.thumb }}" data-rel="{{ category.img }}" alt="{{ category.name }}" title="{{ category.name }}" class="img-thumbnail" /></div>
                {% endif %}
              </div>     
              <a href="{{ category.href }}">{{ category.name }}</a>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
```

But the images are still not displaying. What seems to be the problem? Please help

Answer (score 0):

the only issue I see is that you have written = instead of => in your array.

```
$data['categories'][] = array(
    ...
    'thumb' = $thumb,
```

should be

```
$data['categories'][] = array(
    ...
    'thumb' => $thumb,
```

if that is just a misspell and you still don't see the rendered images, try this:

1. clear twig cache (here http://joxi.ru/YmEaw4LUwM67Nm)
2. check your system/storage/modification folder to check that you don't have a cached modification file of your controller or twig view file.